# Populating new DataFrame by multi-criteria selection from old one with different structure

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm using Pandas for data analysis. I have an input file like this snippet:

```
   VEH  SEC POS   ACCELL    SPEED
    2   8.4 36.51 -0.2929   27.39
    3   8.4 23.57 -0.7381   33.09
    4   8.4 6.18   0.6164   38.8
    1   8.5 47.76  0        25.57
```

I need to reorganize the data so that the rows are the unique (ordered) values from SEC as the 1st column, and then the other columns would be VEH1_POS, VEH1_SPEED, VEH1_ACCELL, VEH2_POS, VEH2_SPEED, VEH2_ACCELL, etc.:

```
TIME VEH1_POS  VEH1_SPEED  VEH1_ACCEL  VEH2_POS, VEH2_SPEED, etc.
0.1   6.2        3.7         0.0        7.5       2.1    
0.2   6.8        3.2        -0.5        8.3       2.1
etc.
```

So, for example, the value for VEH1_POS for each row in the new dataframe would be filled in by selecting values from the POS column in the original dataframe using the row where the SEC value matches the TIME value for the row in the new dataframe and the VEH value == 1.

To set up the rows in the new data frame I'm doing this:

```
start = inputdf['SIMSEC'].min()
end = inputdf['SIMSEC'].max()
time_steps = frange(start, end, 0.1)
outputdf['TIME'] = time_steps
```

But I'm lost at how to select the right values from the input dataframe and create the rest of the new dataframe for further analysis. Note also that the input file will NOT have data for every VEH for every SEC (time stamp). So the solution needs to handle that as well. My best guess was:

```
outputdf['veh1_pos'] = np.where((inputdf['VEH NO'] == 1) & (inputdf['SIMSEC'] == row['Time Step']))
```

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

# your data
# ==========================
print(df)

Out[272]: 
   VEH  SEC    POS  ACCELL  SPEED
0    2  8.4  36.51 -0.2929  27.39
1    3  8.4  23.57 -0.7381  33.09
2    4  8.4   6.18  0.6164  38.80
3    1  8.5  47.76  0.0000  25.57

# reshaping
# ==========================
result = df.set_index(['SEC','VEH']).unstack()

Out[278]: 
       POS                     ACCELL                          SPEED                    
VEH      1      2      3     4      1       2       3       4      1      2      3     4
SEC                                                                                     
8.4    NaN  36.51  23.57  6.18    NaN -0.2929 -0.7381  0.6164    NaN  27.39  33.09  38.8
8.5  47.76    NaN    NaN   NaN      0     NaN     NaN     NaN  25.57    NaN    NaN   NaN
```

So here, the column has multi-level index where 1st level is `POS, ACCELL, SPEED` and 2nd level is `VEH=1,2,3,4`.

```
# if you want to rename the column
temp_z = result.columns.get_level_values(0)
temp_y = result.columns.get_level_values(1)
temp_x = ['VEH'] * len(temp_y)

result.columns = ['{}{}_{}'.format(x,y,z) for x,y,z in zip(temp_x, temp_y, temp_z)]

Out[298]: 
     VEH1_POS  VEH2_POS  VEH3_POS  VEH4_POS  VEH1_ACCELL  VEH2_ACCELL  VEH3_ACCELL  VEH4_ACCELL  VEH1_SPEED  VEH2_SPEED  VEH3_SPEED  VEH4_SPEED
SEC                                                                                                                                            
8.4       NaN     36.51     23.57      6.18          NaN      -0.2929      -0.7381       0.6164         NaN       27.39       33.09        38.8
8.5     47.76       NaN       NaN       NaN            0          NaN          NaN          NaN       25.57         NaN         NaN         NaN
```